# Update from join only if it does not have a row with date higher than now

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables one is `Members` and the other is `Subscriptions`

In the `Members` table I have the following

```
| Members |
-------------------------------
| Person_id | Name | Category |
-------------------------------
|     1     | Bob  |     2    |
|     2     | Anne |     2    |
-------------------------------
```

In the `Subscriptions` table I have the following

```
| Subscriptions |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Subscription_id | Person_id | Start_date |  End_date  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|       1         |     1     | 01-01-2017 | 01-02-2017 |
|       1         |     1     | 01-02-2017 | 01-03-2017 |
|       1         |     1     | 01-03-2017 | 01-04-2017 |
|       2         |     1     | 01-02-2017 | 01-02-2018 |
|       1         |     2     | 01-11-2016 | 01-12-2016 |
|       1         |     2     | 01-12-2016 | 01-01-2017 |
|       2         |     2     | 01-12-2015 | 01-12-2016 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to set the `Category` in the `Members` table to `0` for Members who do not have a subscription in the `Subscriptions` table with a `End_date` higher than current date.

I managed to make a Select query for this but I couldn't change it into an update query

Here is the query

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT m.Person_id, m.Category, MAX(s.End_date) as 'End_date_max'
    FROM 
        Subscriptions s
    JOIN 
        Members m 
        ON m.Person_id = s.Person_id 
        AND m.Category > 0 
        AND m.Category IS NOT NULL 
        AND m.Category <> 1
    GROUP BY m.Person_id
) a
WHERE End_date_max < curdate()
```

So in our case above I would want the member Anne's category changed to 0 because it doesn't have any subscription higher than today

Comment: `update members join (select ...) tmp on ... set category = 0 where ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query [I know I'm not using a Group by, but it should work]

```
UPDATE Members m
SET Category = 0
  WHERE m.Person_id NOT IN (SELECT s.Person_id FROM Subscriptions s
    WHERE s.End_date > curdate())
  AND m.Category > 0 
  AND m.Category IS NOT NULL 
  AND m.Category <> 1
```

Comment: Returns `1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: I changed it to reflect the correct ans, hope it works